# sitecore 9 installation failed on task 11 webdeploy Method not found WebDeployEventWriter EventWriteVerbose

Tags: sitecore, webdeploy, powershell-5.0, sitecore9

I am getting below error while installing sitecore 9.0 update 2 on task 11 .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After troubleshooting I came to know that I had install web deploy 4 which is not supported to SIF 1.2.1

I uninstall and reinstall version 3 problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Installed **Web Deploy** in
>   Visual Studio before to run installtion script.

[image]

Use the search box to search following tools and add as depicted in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sanjay for your response, I found root cause for above error... I had install webdeploy 4 which is not supported to sitecore installation package. I uninstall 4.0 web deploy and install version 3 and works for me. however you are correct it needs webdeploy 3.6 hosting servers as well.